# different definitions of Nussbaum functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, definite-integrals, supremum-and-infimum

I'm trying to understand the difference between two different definitions of the Nussbaum property for real functions.

---

Have a look at **Definition 1** ( taken from https://doi.org/10.1016/0167-6911(83)90021-X):

An even an differentiable function $f: \mathrm{R} \to \mathrm{R}$ is said to have the Nussbaum property, if for every $y_0 \in \mathrm{R}$,
$$
\sup_{y > y_0} \int_{y_0}^y h(s)\, ds = \infty 
$$
and
$$
\inf_{y > y_0} \int_{y_0}^y h(s)\, ds = -\infty. 
$$

---

Now look at the more ad-hoc **Definition 2** (taken from [some lecture notes, p.22](http://liberzon.csl.illinois.edu/teaching/16ece517notes.pdf))

A function $f$ is said to have the Nussbaum property, if

$$
\sup_{y> 0} \frac 1 y \int_0^y f(s) s \,ds = \infty
$$
and
$$
\inf_{y>0} \frac 1 y \int_0^y f(s) s \, ds = - \infty.
$$

---

Examples:

1. $f(s) = s \cos(s)$ has the Nussbaum property only according to **Definition 2** ([plot for D2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot++1%2Fy*(integral+s*cos(s)*s+for+s+%3D+0+to+y)%2C+y%3D-100..100))([plot for D1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%20(integrate%20s*cos(s)%20ds%20from%20s%20%3D%200%20..%20y)%20%2C%20y%3D-100..100)), as $f$ is not even
2. $f(s) = s \sin(s)$ has the Nussbaum property according to **Definition 1** and **Definition 2** ([plot for D1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%20(integrate%20s*sin(s)%20ds%20from%20s%20%3D%200%20..%20y)%20%2C%20y%3D-100..100))([plot for D2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%201%2Fy*(integral%20s*sin(s)*s%20for%20s%20%3D%200%20to%20y)%2C%20y%3D-100..100))
3. $f(s) = s^2 \cos(s)$ has the Nussbaum property according to **Definition 1** and **Definition 2** ([plot for D1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%20(integrate%20s%5E2*cos(s)%20ds%20from%20s%20%3D%200%20..%20y)%20%2C%20y%3D-100..100))([plot for D2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%201%2Fy*(integral%20s%5E2*cos(s)*s%20for%20s%20%3D%200%20to%20y)%2C%20y%3D-100..100))

One more example for a non-differentiable function

4. $f(s) = \begin{cases} 
   1, &\text{if } 0 \leq s < 1\\
   -1, &\text{if } 1 \leq s < 3\\
   1, &\text{if } 3 \leq s < 6\\ 
   -1, &\text{if } 6 \leq s < 10\\
   1, &\text{if } 10 \leq s < 15\\
   \ldots
   \end{cases}$  is a Nussbaum function according to **Definition 2**, but not according to **Definition 1**, since it is clearly not differentiable.

Clearly, there exist functions which are Nussbaum according to Def.2, but not according to Def.1. **Hypothesis**: Are the Def-1-Nussbaum functions a subset to the Def-2-Nussbaum functions then?

On the other hand, requiring $y > 0$ in Def.1 is much more general than requiring $y > y_0$ for every $y_0 \in \mathrm{R}$ as in Def.2. However, since we're dealing with suprema and infima, we surely can neglect some compact intervals in most but the edgiest cases?

Can anyone give a counterexample to my Hypothesis or give some hints or ideas on how I should start the formal proof?

---

Lastly, I consider coming up with my own **Definition 3** as a variant to Definition 2:

A function $f$ is said to have the Nussbaum property, if for every $y_0 \in \mathrm{R}$,

$$
\sup_{y> y_0} \frac 1 {y- y_0} \int_{y_0}^y f(s) s \,ds = \infty
$$
and
$$
\inf_{y> y_0} \frac 1 {y - y_0} \int_{y_0}^y f(s) s \, ds = - \infty.
$$

---

If a function is a Def-3-Nussbaum function, it also is a Def-2-Nussbaum function per definition. Is the opposite also true, i.e. are Def-3 and Def-2 equivalent?